# How to undefine a command with arguments?

Tags: optional-arguments, arguments, definition

I am trying to define `\d` as `\delta` in mathmode, but apparently `\d` is defined as a dot below and it needs an argument: `\d{a}` would give an `a` with a dot below. How can I do this? Here are the packages I am using and wouldn't want to remove because I am not sure what they do exactly

```
\documentclass[20pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage[skip=8pt,font=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6.5in, 9.63in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
```

If I run

```
\let\d\undefined
\renewcommand{\d}{\delta}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\d
\end{align*}

\end{document
```

I get `! LaTeX Error: \d undefined.`

Comment: `\documentclass[20pt]{report}` report does not have a 20pt option.

Comment: If you want help with an error please show the full error from the log from `! to `?` (see my answer) and post an example document (without any packages not needed to show the error) that produces the error. The code posted does not produce `Missing } inserted`

Comment: are you sure you want `\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}` ? It is almost always better to simply use luatex's built in utf-8 unless you have particular need for extra compatibility with inputenc with pdftex.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need the `\let`.

```
\renewcommand{\d}{\delta}
```

will redefine `\d`.  However this is almost always a bad idea, any uses of under dots will use `\d` expecting that it is not redefined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1ECD}{\d{o}}

\begin{document}

[ọ]
\end{document}
```

Is supposed to work, so if you redefine `\d` you need to find every use of `\d` anywhere and change it to use a different command for an under accent.

The posted code does not produce the missing `}` error that you state, it produces

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \d undefined.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.24 \renewcommand{\d}
                      {\delta}
```

as you have undefined `\d` if you delete the line

```
\let\d\undefined
```

then it runs without error.

Comment: Is there any way using `\ifmmode` test?

Comment: @MarianG.  You could but not redefining standard latex commands would  be my strong recommendation.

Comment: I added my attempt below. Feel free to downvote my answer if it is bad.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it is still the same error if I remove `\let\d\undefined`

Comment: The code posted produces no error. If you posted a code that produces the `missing }` error then someone could debug it.

Comment: @MBolin I don't usually downvote, however the answer is bad advice and doesn't work, I added some fail cases in comments below the answer

Answer (score 1):

## Update (according to comments of D. Carlisle)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldd\d

\protected\def\d{%
    \ifmmode\delta\else\expandafter\oldd\fi}

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt


text mode: \d a
\bigskip

math mode: $\delta\frac{1}{2}$, $\begin{array}{c}\d\gamma\end{array}$, $\d^2$
\end{document}
```

## Original attempt

I'm not an expert, but it seems that the following approach also work. It would be very nice if someone discuss in more detail if the presented attempt is safe.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\oldd\d

\def\d#1{%
    \ifmmode\delta\else\oldd{#1}\fi
    \ifmmode#1\fi}

\begin{document}
\parindent0pt


text mode: \d a
\bigskip

math mode: $\d^2-4\text{\d a}$, $\d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I write `$\d$` I get `! Missing $ inserted.`

Comment: @MBolin: Thank you for your feedback. Corrected.

Comment: This fails `$\begin{array}{c}  \d \gamma \end{array} $`  This gives no error but makes nonsensical output `$ \d \frac{1}{2} $` basically the redefinition breaks latex, it is not recommended.

Comment: if you want to do this then `\protected\def\d{\ifmmode\delta\else\expandafter\oldd\fi}` but it is still not recommended.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You are right. Thank you for your valuable comments. I added an update to my bad answer.